# Print n rows in columns by using format in python

Tags: python, list, format

I want to print n rows into columns. With columns size depending on the longest data in each row.

I have somthing like

`data = [['abcdefghijk', 'b','c'],['121','313','5441256652'],['--','310','36']['642','65','10']]`

and want to turn it into

```
abcdefghijk    121           --     642
b              313           310    65
c              5441256652    36     10
```

Each column width is length of the longest element in the row + 4

I know for this case i could use

```
row_format ='{:<15}{:<14}{:<7}{:<7}'
for v in zip(*data):
    print (row_format.format(*v))
```

But how do i get the same pattern with n rows in data, without knowing the length of the elements in advance?

Comment: Do all rows share the same length? What's the format in case one row is longer than the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically build the `row_format` string:

```
row_format = ''.join(f'{{:<{len(max(x, key=len)) + 4}}}' for x in data)
for v in zip(*data):
    print (row_format.format(*v))
```

For example, this data

```
data = [['a', 'bbbbbb', 'c'],
        ['121', '313', '0'],
        ['------', '310', '36'],
        ['3', '455', '5']]
```

is printed in this way:

```
a         121    ------    3      
bbbbbb    313    310       455    
c         0      36        5
```

Comment: With this format all columns have the same width. Is it possible to make the width also dynamic?

Comment: @JanBe Dynamic depending on what? Please edit your original question with a more complicated example and **the expected output**

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. I edited the example, i hope it is more clear now.
Thank you

Comment: @JanBe it's still not clear. What's the specific rule to decide how many spaces to use?

Comment: for example the longest element in the row + 4 as column width. I want it to be lined up so the user can read it easily

Comment: @JanBe All right, I edited my answer. Please upvote it and mark it as accepted if you think it is useful. If you have other questions please open a new thread :)